# clear up GM_log from error console

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

Is there a way to clear up GM_log messages from error console from userscripts on a certain event?

I don't want to clear up manually. `On trigger of certain event, want to clear up the old log from the error console and show up the new log.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot clear [the error console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Error_Console).  If you could, evil websites could clear it too and erase the record of their misdeeds.

You should no longer use `GM_Log()` anyway.  [Use Firebug](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_log#GM_log_and_Firebug) and [the excellent console logging functions it provides](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API).

Then you can use `console.clear()`.

Note, to avoid conflicts with Firefox's newish `console` functions, and to ensure that the output appears in Firebug's console, you may need to prefix the calls with `unsafeWindow`.

So your script could do something like this:

```
unsafeWindow.console.clear ();
unsafeWindow.console.time ('ScriptRun');

unsafeWindow.console.log ("Script start." );
unsafeWindow.console.timeEnd ('ScriptRun');
```

Which would look like this in the Firebug console:
[image: Console result]

-- with all the preceding cruft erased.  (Anything the webpage does after the `clear()` call will still appear though.)